# Sharing files and folders on Mac

Tags: sharing

Sharing files and folders on Mac somehow confuses me. There are `Public Folder`, `Drop Boxes` and `Shared Folder`. What confuses me is the following:

- Which one of the above to use when sharing folders between multiple users on the same Mac?
- Is sharing folders using any of the above makes it available to whoever on the same network?
- How to share folders and files between users and not network?

Comment: Why don't you remove each of the default shares and then add only the share you need with the permission you want. Much easier to take away un-needed shares and then intentionally make and grant permissions to me what makes sense to you.

Answer (score 2):

There's an [Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25262?locale=en_US) that explains these three folders. These folders are for sharing files with users of the **same Mac**, and by default are **not** used for transferring files through the network.

- The `Shared` folder is located in `/Users`.
- Your `Public` folder is in your home folder. Each user has one by default.
- Your `Drop Box` folder is in your `Public` folder.

The `Shared` and `Public` folders can be read by anyone, regardless of administrator access. However, only the owner of a file (i.e. the user who put it there) can modify or remove it.

The `Drop Box` folder is used to share items with another user, and not every user on the Mac. Anyone can put items in the folder by dragging and dropping it into the user's `Drop Box`. However, only the user that owns the folder can open and read what's inside the folder.

If you want to allow **any user** on the Mac to have access to these files, use the `Shared` folder or your `Public` folder. If you want to share a file with a **limited** amount of user(s), put the file in their `Drop Box` folder(s) located in their `Public` folder(s).

Answer (score 0):

The shared folder is for users on the same computer.  For example if you install an application that all users can access.  Depending on the computer you might not have permission to do this, for example if it is a work or public computer the administrator might restrict a user's ability to make global changes on the system.

The public folder is a folder within your user account that you can access to share documents with others on the same computer.  This is associated with your login and doesn't require administrator privileges.

Drop Box is a third party application that allows remote access of files, either by yourself or others if you give them permission.  Therefore files in a Drop Box folder are those that are sync'd to your Drop Box in the cloud.

The page below has step-by-step instructions and has more information on how to edit permissions:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25605?locale=en_US

Comment: I think the original question was referring to the Drop Box folder that is contained within each user's Public folder. This folder is write-only for all accounts other than the owner. So it's a place for other accounts to share files with you, without them being able to see what else is already in the folder.